"Last seen more than x ago" is sometimes inaccurate
"Last seen more than x ago" is sometimes inaccurate. Example (mirror): "Last seen more than 1 month ago", even though they posted a question 22h ago.

https://shouldiblamecaching.com/ possibly?

22 hours should be sufficient time for the system to catch up, seems excessive - unless there's something going on with maintenance we don't know about.

No bug and nothing weird.
The question was originally asked on Super User, then later migrated to other site.
That user didn't visit that other site yet.
This can be seen when going to the question, and there's a banner on top:




Thanks, feel free to remove the question since this is incorrect bug report.

No need to delete, this can be confusing as there's no sign the question was asked in different place, unless you actually go and view it. So others might get confused as well in the future, and this can be used to explain the case.
